# Finding the residue of a mod of a function...

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, absolute-value, residue-calculus

What is the residue of
$$f(z)=\frac{1}{|z+c||z-c|}$$ at
$z=c$ and $z=-c$.
I know to find the residue without mod in the denominator, but I have no idea of finding the residue with a mod in the denominator.

Comment: This is not a meromorphic function: how do you define the residue?

Answer (score 0):

The notion of residue, only makes sense if the function can be expanded in Laurent series of variable $z$:
$$
f(z) = \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_n z^{n}
$$
Due to the abs symbol $\vert \ldots \vert$, you will have to write the function in terms of both $z, \bar{z}$, residue is not defined.

Comment: So can we integrate this function from $+\infty \to -\infty$@spiridon_the_sun_rotator